# What is the difference between fetch Next and fetch First in the Order By [...] OFFSET [..] FETCH [...] clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I executed two sample queries on AdventureWorks2016 and gave me the same result.
When should I use NEXT or FIRST keyword then?

```
select LastName + ' ' + FirstName 
from person.person
order by LastName asc OFFSET 10 rows **Fetch next** 10 rows only

select LastName + ' ' + FirstName
from person.person
order by LastName asc OFFSET 10 rows **Fetch first** 10 rows only
```

Comment: I guess running it AGAIN will fetch rows 11-20 in first case, but 1-10

Comment: Doesn't matter.

Comment: George. No it' not. I tried DECLARE @i int = 0
WHILE @i < 2
BEGIN
 SET @i = @i + 1

 --select LastName + ' ' + FirstName
 --from person.person
 --order by LastName asc 
 --OFFSET  10  rows 
 --Fetch next 10 rows only

 select LastName + ' ' + FirstName
 from person.person
 order by LastName asc 
 OFFSET  10  rows 
 Fetch first 10 rows only
END

Comment: The difference is only for the human reader. Doesn't make any difference to SQL Server. [FIRST and NEXT can be used interchangeably.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`FETCH FIRST` and `FETCH NEXT` do [exactly the same thing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned). The reason both exist because of the mandatory preceding `OFFSET` keyword. Using the word `FIRST` combined with `OFFSET` can be confusing to a human reader:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Foo
ORDER BY ID
OFFSET 5 ROWS
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY; -- Does this mean rows 6 to 10, or 1 to 5?
```

Whereas:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Foo
ORDER BY ID
OFFSET 5 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY; -- Now it's clear!
```

[SqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9873f/6) here.

Similarly, you can use `ROW` and `ROWS` interchangeably, even if it breaks English grammar norms.

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference. The SQL standard simply allows both, maybe to bridge differences between syntaxes, or to allow you the choice to write 'fluent English' queries.

This similar as to why the standard allows you to write:

```
fetch first row
fetch first rows
fetch first 1 row
fetch first 1 rows
```

(and variants with `next`) which will all fetch a single row. That this also allows you to write grammatically incorrect sentences like `fetch first 2 row` is taken for granted.